# Highcharts in angular scope problem with passing class reference

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I got component that renders chart and I want to overwrite initial tooltips with help of formatter with the data it looks like that:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function () {
    console.log(this);
    // logs data described aboved code snippet
    console.log(this.filterService.getFilters());
    // logs undefined as its component method
  }
}
```

where `console.log(this)` logs data about hovered item on chart, looks like this:

```
{
  x: "xxxxx",
  y: 94,
  color: "#58a310",
  colorIndex: 0,
  key: "xxxxx",
  series: e {proceed: null, chart: a.Chart, userOptions: {…}, tooltipOptions: {…}, 
  stickyTracking: false, …},
  point: C {series: e, color: "#58a310", y: 94, options: {…}, isNull: false, …},
  percentage: 60.256410256410255,
  total: 156,
  ...
}
```

and I need some data from service, which is used by this component, so I can access it by using arrow func for formatter:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: () => {
    // here `this` refers to component class
    console.log(this.filterService.getFilters());
    // logs filters data, which I need 
  }
}
```

So I need both of those (chart item data & filters) to perform operation that I want but, don't see the way to get them both, only one or another dependent on how I declare func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IIFE function to store a component reference:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: (function(component) {
    return function() {
      console.log(component, this);
    }
  })(this)
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4808/